# Image Optimization (iOS)

Tags: ios, image, ipad, memory, optimization

I'm working on a iPad Magazine and I'm using a lot of images (background, slideshow and animation) and the memory utilized is very high.

I've read the following method uses a lot of memory

```
UIImage *picture = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myFile.png"];
```

And they recommended using this one

```
NSString *fullpath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingString:@"/myFile.png"];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullpath];
```

But I've found another method as well

```
imageView.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myFile" ofType:@"png"]];
```

In order to optimize my app, which method should I use? All my images are .jpg and were saved for web in Photoshop.

Comment: "I've read the following method uses a lot of memory" is not true in itself. Also, this has nothing to do with Xcode whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

All 3 methods will use the same amount of memory. The differences are the following:

Using     `[UIImage imageNamed:@"myFile.png"]`   image is cached in memory for faster reuse. This is good for small images used several times in your application (image background, etc). Cache is removed for non used images when memory warning is received.

Using `[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path]` image is not cached and you can "force" release of memory by calling `[image release]` or setting property to nil using ARC. You have a better management of when memory is released

Using `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullpath]` is just equivalent to `[[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path]autorelease]`